# Unable to install proprietary Nvidia driver after last Kali update

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, nvidia

I recently updated my system to the latest Kali release. After that I cannot install proprietary Nvidia driver. I usually follow this process in order to install Nvidia driver after an update:

1. On boot, switch to tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Disable desktop manager `service gdm3 stop`
3. Uninstall driver installed in previous kernel `./NVIDIA-xxx.run --uninstall`
4. Reboot machine `reboot`

After reboot I repeat steps from 1 to 4 changing `--uninstall` to `-a` in step 3. Then generally I have reinstalled successfully the driver.

Yesterday after the last update, when I run `./NVIDIA-xxx.run -a` the installer told me it was compiling the kernel modules, then stopped with a generic error and told me to check file `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log`

Output of `uname -a`:

`Linux kali 4.7.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.8-1kali1 (2016-10-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Nvidia driver attempting to install (it was the same in the previous kernel version and worked fine!):

NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run

`/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` output [here](http://pastebin.com/WhKHEkwC)