# TP-Link Archer T2UH not working on kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have tried installing the TP-Link Archer 2TUH but whenever I got to terminal with the drivers and type "make" get a bunch of errors saying

```
"root@f1nd3r:~/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909# make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL'
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/Archer_T2UH_V1_150909/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2"
```

Is there a fix for this?
Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Luckily, I have an answer to this question.
You have to install kernel headers.

`apt-get install linux-headers-amd64`

That was my situation before, and now you'll face the same error as me, btw let me know if not:

```
root@Unknown:~/Downloads/Driver# make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-kali1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64'
  CC [M]  /root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.c:1:0: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
 /****************************************************************************

/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o' failed
make[5]: *** [/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1488: recipe for target '_module_/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux' failed
make[4]: *** [_module_/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL/os/linux] Error 2
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64'
Makefile:527: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Downloads/Driver/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like this can be the solutionI've got the patch file, but not sure how to get it working - I've copied it to lib/modules/4.8.0-kali-amd64/kernel

Comment: Looks like this can be the solution
[link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320470/apply-kernel-patch-to-support-pic-mode)
I've got the patch file, but not sure how to get it installed - I've copied it to lib/modules/4.8.0-kali-amd64/kernel and tried the command patch -p1 but it seems like just hanging.
I can't comment on that page to ask how to, as I don't have 50reps..
@SpaceGoat